# Jenkins pipeline, pass branchname to gradle build

Tags: jenkins, gradle, groovy, sonarqube, jenkins-pipeline

A multibranch jenkins pipeline calls a gradle build.
Need to pass the `BRANCH_NAME` to the sonarqube task in build.gradle:

```
sonarqube {
  properties {
    property "sonar.host.url", "https://sonar"
    property "sonar.projectKey", "com.foo.bar:Foobar"
    property "sonar.projectName", "com.foo.bar-Foobar"
    property "sonar.binaries", "build"
    property "sonar.branch.name", "${branchname}" <---------------
    property "sonar.branch.target", "master"
  }
}
```

I tried:

```
  stage('Sonarscan') {
    withSonarQubeEnv('SONAR') {
      bat "gradlew -Pbranchname=${BRANCH_NAME} sonarqube --info"
    }
  }
```

output:

```
* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating root project 'fooBar'.
> Cannot get property 'branchname' on extra properties extension as it does not exist
```

and

```
  stage('Sonarscan') {
    withSonarQubeEnv('SONAR') {
      bat "gradlew -Dbranchname=${BRANCH_NAME} sonarqube --info"
    }
  }
```

output:

```
* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating root project 'fooBar'.
> Could not get unknown property 'branchname' for root project 'sfrToolbarContract' of type org.gradle.api.Project.
```

and also:

```
  stage('Sonarscan') {
    withSonarQubeEnv('SONAR') {
      def branchname = "${BRANCH_NAME}"
      bat "gradlew sonarqube --info"
    }
  }
```

but the pipeline jobs just hangs.
How to pass a property from Jenkinsfile to gradle build ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you can directly pass the SonarQube parameter on the command line:

```groovy
stage('Sonarscan') {
  withSonarQubeEnv('SONAR') {
    bat "gradlew sonarqube -Dsonar.branch.name=${BRANCH_NAME} --info"
  }
}
```

Comment: It's important to mention that the branch plugin must be installed, otherwise you will get: Validation of project reactor failed:
    To use the property "sonar.branch.name", the branch plugin is required but not installed. See the documentation of branch support: https://redirect.sonarsource.com/doc/branches.html.